# Upgrde to Clearcase 9

Tags: clearcase

Project has taken so long to decide to upgrade Clearcase from 7.1.2.6 that we 8 going out of support in less than a year we now looking at CC version 9.

Does anyone have any experience or knowledge if potentials pitfalls or issues doing this.

We are using UCM CC with CQ and have seen one post describing an update in how this can work but is there anything else any one has encountered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Common stumbling blocks include:

1. VOB schema version. Since you're on 7.1 already, we at least know your VOB schema is supported.
2. Feature level. If any of your VOBs are not at least feature level 6, you need to update them to FL6 before upgrading CC. See [About feature Levels and ClearCase](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21119269) for more on the available feature levels.
3. Platform support. Between 7.1.x and 9.0, a number of older platforms were explicitly desupported, among them XP, Windows 2003, Solaris 10, Red Hat Linux 4 & 5, etc. You may have to update the OS, which may require a hardware update. You should review the [ClearCase 9.0 Detailed System requirements](https://www.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=A3D092300DF211E5A377F80D5A43BD22&osPlatforms=Windows) to verify whether your server and client hosts need to be updated in order to support the new release.
4. Integration changes. If you are using older development tools, they may no longer integrate with the current ClearCase release.
5. User Interface changes. ClearCase 9 includes an Eclipse-based client called ClearTeam Explorer which has some, but not necessarily all, of the functionality from CC Explorer, Project Explorer, the vtree browser, and some merge tools. Those older tools still work, largely the way they did before warts and all.

There is a lot of work in 9.0 to make ClearCase more "thread-friendly" to allow for multithreading some server processes in subsequent releases. Some of this (view and albd improvements) should show up fairly soon in 9.0.1.

As with any large system migration, setting up a test environment would be recommended to locate any issues with tool integrations before rolling it out in production.

Comment: Brian, Many thanks for this. I'm just getting our test environment set up with vob and view servers being on separate Windows Server 2012 boxes. Our vobs are currently at FL 5 & Schema 54. Would we still need to update to FL6 even if we are only updating the Server side initially? Or would FL6 be a pre-req for even that? Our original hope had been to move to new servers at Ver 9 then at a later date have another outage to increase the FL & Schema.

Comment: The feature level has to be brought up to at least 6 first. If you are using replicated, VOBS this is critical. Schema does not have to be brought up immediately.

Comment: Thanks Brian, we don't have replicated VOBS so could be ok to up the FL after migration. Now trying to negotiate the appropraite outage to do all this.

Comment: I would not recommend waiting until after migration to update the feature level. Updating the feature level in a non-replicated environment isn't generally something you need an outage for. In this particular case, the only significant add is Multisite-specific, so there *should* not be any nasty surprises, but the "official party line" is that Feature Level 5 VOBs are not supported in current ClearCase releases.

Comment: Thanks, For now this bullet has been dodged and our client is going to go with extended support on Ver 8